# oracle connect by prior using with the part of the composite key make malformed result?

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

```
SELECT xml_tag,TAG_ID,tag_id,parent_id,position_id,LEVEL //position_id for identify siblings 
FROM   Intrastat_Xml_Template_TAB
WHERE  country_code = countrycode_ //country_code(varchar) and TAG_ID(number) makes the composite key
START  WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR tag_id = parent_id
ORDER  SIBLINGS BY position_id;
```

when I execute this it's given vary large number of row set as out put, more than the total number of records in the  **Intrastat_Xml_Template_TAB**. In this case composite key look like as follow

```
1   DE,
2   DE,
3   DE,
4   DE,
5   DE,
1   SI,
2   SI,
3   SI
```

IF table data in below arrangement it work fine

```
1   DE,
2   DE,
3   DE,
4   DE,
5   DE,
6   SI,
7   SI,
8   SI
```

any explanation for why this is happening. And any suggestion to fix this issue.
Thanks and Best Regards 
Osura

Comment: As far as I understand your question the answer is `DE` rows are connected to `SI` rows. `where` clause is not enough here, you can check it using `sys_connect_by_path` like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1eb93591a8ba8debd2664f669973159f). You should add `country_code` to `connect by` and `start with` clauses.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thanks  for the solution it works perfect 